# openCV: library extension with CMAKE

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I built OpenCV from sources using CMAKE on windows and I notice that the compiled libraries have the version extensions. So, I have libs that are built with the name like: `opencv_dnn341.lib` where `341`, I guess represents opencv version 3.4.1.

Now, when I try to use this in another CMAKE project, I have this to find opencv. Something like:

```
#cmake/opencv/CMakeLists.txt
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)
SET(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    CACHE INTERNAL "OpenCV include dirs"
)
SET(OpenCV_LIBS ${OpenCV_LIBS}
    CACHE INTERNAL "OpenCV libs"
)
```

Now, I try to list the opencv libraries from CMAKE as:

```
MESSAGE( STATUS "OPENCV_LIBS:      ${OpenCV_LIBS}" )
```

This lists the libraries as:

```
 opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;...
```

Notice that the `341` is missing from the filenames. As a result, my Visual Studio project cannot find these libraries. Why is CMAKE not generating the correct library names?

**EDIT**

My CMakeLists dealing with finding OpenCV is:

```
 #cmake/opencv/CMakeLists.txt
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.2.0)

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)
SET(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    CACHE INTERNAL "OpenCV include dirs"
)
SET(OpenCV_LIBS ${OpenCV_LIBS}
    CACHE INTERNAL "OpenCV libs"
)
```

I use it in my top level CMakeLists as:

```
PROJECT(RTFilter)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.2.0)

SET(USE_OPENCV ON CACHE BOOL "ON OFF")
MARK_AS_ADVANCED(USE_OPENCV)

SET(HEADERS
  nort.h    
)

SET(SOURCES
  main.cpp
)

if(USE_OPENCV)
    ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(cmake/opencv)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

    # TODO Need to infer the path of the OpenCV libs
    LINK_DIRECTORIES(${OpenCV_DIR}/x64/vc15/lib)
    message(STATUS, "LIBS: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    LIST(APPEND LIBS ${OpenCV_LIBS})

    ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DUSE_OPENCV)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(opencv)
    LIST(APPEND HEADERS opencv/rtfilter.h)
    LIST(APPEND SOURCES opencv/rtfilter.cpp)
endif(USE_OPENCV)

# Compile and link
ADD_LIBRARY(${NAME} SHARED ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${NAME} ${LIBS})
```

Comment: Those are not names of library files, those are names of CMake targets from `OpenCVModules.cmake` and related files.

Comment: @DanMašek But this is the output from `${OPENCV_LIBS}` variable which should point to the libraries? I see the library names in the install directories with the `341` suffix

Comment: ***variable which should point to the libraries*** Not if they are imported targets. target_link_libraries( ) should find the correct library names and use that when it generates your project.

Comment: I might be very confused. The examples I have looked at using OpenCV have basically used this CMAKE configurartion. What should I be using to ensure that I can link to the correct libraries? Is there something I should change in the opencv configuration and build again?

Comment: ***Is there something I should change in the opencv configuration and build again?*** I expect the answer is no. You likely built OpenCV correctly.

Comment: Please add your minimal CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @drescherjm Added the CMakeLists

Comment: `LINK_DIRECTORIES(${OpenCV_DIR}/x64/vc15/lib)` -- that looks suspect, `OpenCVModules-release.cmake` already specifies those paths relative to the install dir...

Comment: According to [FindOpenCV.cmake](https://github.com/veter-team/cmake-modules/blob/master/windows/FindOpenCV.cmake#L77) script, it extracts version from `cvver.h` header file. Make sure that your OpenCV installation has this file, and exactly it is found by "Find" script (check content of `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR` variable).

Comment: @DanMašek Even without it, I get the same error. Initially, the VS Additional Directories path was empty, so I thought I had to set this up...Even without them, I have the same issue.

Comment: @Luca Did you manage to solve it? I have the same issue